# HTML formatting in VSCode

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I want to sometimes put comments after closing tags in my HTML documents, but when the file gets formatted the comments get moved to a new line.

I am trying to figure out how to set the editor to leave the comments where I put them. I started by looking at the preferences, then google search and then Stack Overflow. I've looked through many interesting articles that seem related, but have not hit on one that shows my particular issue.

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: It looks like this is a bug/enhancement request, see https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/426  An old issue with no progress.  VSCode uses js-beautify.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will check the link you provided...